# Rails does not generate an authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, csrf

I'm following these two tutorials altogether,

- https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

and implementing a simple comment system in Rails. However, I got a problem with handling the submit. I implemented a simple AJAX POST request to send my form data (as state). It looks like this:

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    handleChange: function(e) {
    var name, obj;
    name = e.target.name;
    return this.setState((
      obj = {},
      obj["" + name] = e.target.value,
      obj
    ));
  },
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var author = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.author).value.trim();
        var text   = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value.trim();
        if(!text || !author) {
            return;
        }
        $.post(this.props.postUrl, {comment: this.state}, null, "application/json");
        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.author).value = '';
        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value = '';
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="author" name="author" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." ref="text" name="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
        );
    }
});
```

As I examined the console, It looks like it is passing to the right route and the right params, except no authenticity_token param. Here is a screen shot of what is in the console.

[image]

In the first link that I've provided, it is said that jquery_ujs handles generating and passing an authenticity token to Ajax POST. However, this is not true in my case. What am I missing?

**Edit:**
I've got a few answers that would fix my problem. However, I'm still curios about what makes the difference between my code and the code at this tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.** 
Removed the line

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

from application.html.erb. It turns out that it was shadowing the jquery_rails while making an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are missing in your `render` method to pass an `authenticity_token`. Either you disable the authenticity check (**not** recommended), or you deliver your rendered form with an authenticity token.

In this case i would recommend to use Gon for clean passing of controller variables to JS: https://github.com/gazay/gon

When you installed it:

In your controller method:

```
gon.authenticity_token = form_authenticity_token
```

In your react class:

```
<form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value={gon.authenticity_token}  />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="author" name="author" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." ref="text" name="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I was not considering to disable the check, too. But I still wonder what makes this difference between his tutorial and my code?

Comment: I just checked his tutorial, he didn't paste his ApplicationController, so i can't tell if he has `protect_from_forgery` activated or not, at least in his own controllers he doesn't use it

Comment: Yep, thought about it too, but he explicitly says that:
"If you have used other JS frameworks along with Rails (for example, AngularJS) to build similar features, you might have run into problems because your POST requests don't include the CSRF token required by Rails, so, why didn't we run into this same issue? Easy, because we are using jQuery to interact with our backend, and Rails' jquery_ujs unobtrusive driver will include the CSRF token on every AJAX request for us. Cool!" 
That is what confuses me. Just sent him an email.

Comment: I see, i didn't come up to that section, but i'm wondering if it's related to https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L70 - can you confirm that your ajax call is sending the request header `X-CSRF-Token`?

Comment: Because you could have forgot to include http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper/csrf_meta_tags in your layout, that would explain the missing value to include in the request headers.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `authenticity_token` attribute to your `AJAX POST`:

you could replace this line:

```
$.post(this.props.postUrl, {comment: this.state}, null, "application/json");
```

with this:

```
$.post(this.props.postUrl, {
    comment: this.state,
    authenticity_token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
  }, null, "application/json");
```